# meaning of "I have everything for my xxx"

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/T-HGdc8L-7w?t=989)

> And I **have everything for** my class.

Which uses the pattern `I have everything for my xxx`. Another use could be

> I have everything for my party.

I guess it's a more colloquial than "everything is ready".

However, [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&ei=TS4lX4L8Ffa00PEPib2cwAg&q=%22have%20everything%20for%20my%20party%22&oq=%22have%20everything%20for%20my%20party%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1AAWABgr5QJaAJwAHgAgAGLAogBiwKSAQMyLTGYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjC1o-u0fnqAhV2GjQIHYkeB4gQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) only returns 3 hits.

Is it clear and natural to say "I have everything for my party"?

Comment: Yes. It's shorthand for saying **everything I require/need** for xxx. If in doubt, spell it out.

Comment: "Have everything for **the** party" returns 570,000 hits.

Comment: Note that “I have everything” means you have the supplies you need, while “everything is ready” means preparations are complete. Having all the ingredients for a cake doesn’t mean the cake is ready to eat; you still have to bake it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence. It is clear and natural. I am genuinely surprised at how few hits it returns. Of course, it now returns 4 hits, because thanks to your question, this page comes up! But your example is very specific. The more specific your sentence, the fewer results it will return.

- "I have everything for" returns 2,280,000 hits.
- "I have everything I need for" returns 1,620,000 hits.

You could also say "a party", "the party", "your party", as well as "my party" and the sentence would still be grammatical.