# the position of "only" to emphasize the rareness

Tags: adverbs

In the post [meaning of "I have everything for my xxx"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/256413/117396) I said

> However, googling it **only** returns 3 hits.

I was trying to emphasize the rareness of the searching results. Should I have put it this way?

> However, googling it returns **only** 3 hits.

Which one should I use?

Are there any other expressions clearer and more natural could be used here?

Answer (score 1):

**Only** is a creeper.

In colloquial English it tends to make its way towards the front of a sentence when it is intended to modify a later word or section.

So a sentence such as: **I only saw him while he was working in his garage yesterday** should be rewritten as: **I saw him only yesterday while he was working in his garage**.

In your examples, **only** is intended to modify **hits**. So, to be clear, you should place it just in front of **3 hits**.

But in practice, it's likely that many English speakers would use it in front of **returns** when they meant it to modify **3 hits**.

Comment: Thank you. The adverb "just" shares the same rules with it with the meaning of "only", right?

Comment: A pedant would say that _I  only baked two pies_ means _I only baked them, I didn't do anything else to them_ - but in practice, everyone would understand it to mean the same as _I baked only two pies_.

Comment: +1 for "creeper"! It's perhaps worth noting that near-synonymous ***just*** is far less likely to "creep forwards" like this. And no such issue can arise with *Googling it returns **a mere** 3 hits* (where ***merely*** isn't particularly idiomatic anyway - but again, that one would tend to stick close to the referent noun).